# Windows login required when debugging web page from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I recently received a new workstation with Windows 7 SP1 and Visual Studio 2010 SP1. Every time I start debugging an ASP.NET web site I am required to provide my computer login (pretty annoying).

Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dev webserver requires administrative rights in order to run, so you can do one of the following:

- Run Visual Studio as Administrator.
- The more secure option: use [IIS Express](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/) (or full IIS) instead of the dev web server.